# no emulation booting OS

Tags: x86, operating-system, bootloader, osdev, dvd

I'm working on **no-emulation** booting OS , as you know in **no-emulation** booting, the boot image can be any
(real-mode) binary executable code.

i use 2 stage bootloader for my os , first i load the fist stage 
the problem that i encounter is in the second stage, When the bootloader tries to load the OS image, it needs a device number
of the CD/DVD drive to make BIOS calls

The question is: which device number i should use  ?

i have tryed `0x81`(first IDE slave) and  `0x82` (the second IDE master)
on some pc it work on others it not

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you give a little more detail pls

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head.  But if you search on https://wiki.osdev.org/ you should find something.  (Or probably one of @MichaelPetch's answers here on SO.)  Or look in the related sidebar; there's a question with "dl register and drive number" in the title.

Comment: In No Emulation mode your bootloader can query for the boot drive with  [INT 13H AH=4Bh, AL=1](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0719.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The El Torito (CD-ROM standard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)) protocol only states that `BIOS` shall emulate the
`CD/DVD` drive by an arbitrary device number.

Different `BIOS` may come up with
different drive numbers.

when BIOS invokes a bootloader, it also passes the
emulated drive number in the CPU’s **`DL` register**.

The bootloader must catch the drive
number and use it to make BIOS calls.

and the rest of it is similar to emulation booting